# Firebase Quota has been exceeded for this project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi am a little confuse on how this works base on firebase quotas on the free plan, been testing my app for months now and never came across this issue. How can i resolve or detect this issue where after couple of hours my quota is exceeded.

```
 {
      "error": {
        "code": 402,
        "message": "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to learn more."
      }
    }

    <Error>
    <Code>InsufficientQuota</Code>
    <Message>
    The App Engine application does not have enough quota.
    </Message>
    <Details>
    NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA: App xxxxxxxxxxx does not have enough quota
    </Details>
    </Error>
```

Comment: Did you visit the firebase pricing page?

Comment: yes, but i am the only one storing files and making request thats why am lost as to how i managed to reach the limit within hours.

Comment: Firebase is actually prone to some bandwidth calculation errors, but before we point fingers here, what firebase services are you making use of here? maybe there's something you're missing

Comment: Am using "Spark Plan Generous limits for hobbyists Free". Cloud functions, Database, Storage, Crashlytics, Authentications.

Comment: Did you look at the usage tab in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)? It will show you the usage over time for the past period. Then have a look at your code and investigate where the bandwidth usage comes from. The [database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) might be useful for that.

Comment: After some investigations i found out i can't read or write images. Every other data is passed fine. Also the usage looks fair and ok to me else am missing something.

Connections
10 / 100 peak
Storage
160.1 KB / 1 GB
Downloads
188.9 MB / 10 GB
Load
2% peak

Comment: I recommend you contact Firebase support to get direct insight into what's going on in your project.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Just did that thanks all.